# Applying lambda to whole dataframe with if condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` that looks like this:

```
A
0
1
2
2.5
0
9.5
0
```

I want to calculate the mean of the columns where `A>0` so that my `df` would look like this:

```
A       B
0       0
1       3.75
2       3.75
2.5     3.75
0       0
9.5     3.75
0       0
```

I use:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x[x['A']>0].mean())
```

But get:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

I also tried

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x['A']>0].mean(), axis=1)
```

But get:

> KeyError: False

Which is produced by the `x['A']>0` mask.

And:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x['A']>0].mean() if x['A']>0 else 0, axis=1)
```

I couldn't find a solution how can I apply a lambda function to a filtered dataframe. I could write a function, but wanted to know if its possible with `apply(lambda)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternately you could use `groupby` and `transform` like

```
df['B'] = df.groupby(df['A'].gt(0)).transform('mean')
df

     A    B
0   0.0 0.00
1   1.0 3.75
2   2.0 3.75
3   2.5 3.75
4   0.0 0.00
5   9.5 3.75
6   0.0 0.00
```

Comment: This is actually the cleanest version here

Comment: @JBernardo, by cleanest do you think of writing-wise or performance and best practice-like?

Answer (score 2):

In general, avoid `apply` and `applymap` since they are not vectorized. Plus, in your case, you need to access the information from the whole dataframe/series, while `apply/applymap` only gives you information of the individual cells, so it is not the best choice for this use case.

Use `loc` access and `np.where`:

```
mask = df['A'] > 0
df['B'] = np.where(mask, df.loc[mask, 'A'].mean(), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it correct to translate your point to avoid `apply` and `applymap` because they are slow? (not vectorized == slow)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.mask`:

```
df["B"] = df["A"].mask(df["A"]>0, df.loc[df["A"].ne(0), "A"].mean())

print (df)

     A     B
0  0.0  0.00
1  1.0  3.75
2  2.0  3.75
3  2.5  3.75
4  0.0  0.00
5  9.5  3.75
6  0.0  0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution

```
df['B'] = 0
df['B'][df['A'] > 0] = df['A'][df['A'] > 0].mean()
```

Output:

```
     A     B
0  0.0  0.00
1  1.0  3.75
2  2.0  3.75
3  2.5  3.75
4  0.0  0.00
5  9.5  3.75
6  0.0  0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple approach

```
df['B'] = 0
df.B[df.A > 0] = df[df.A > 0].mean().A
```